# How to add user profile page in the navigation bar, under sign out button in oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex

How can I add a button with redirect to user profile page, right under the sign out button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sign out/User profile menu items are part of a list (Shared Components > Lists).

- By default, the name of this list is "Desktop Navigation Bar".
- By default, the sign out option has the &APP_USER. entry as a parent

Add a new entry with a sequence higher than the "Sign Out" entry and set "&APP_USER." as the parent.

Note: I said "by default" above because this all can be completely customised, but for an application created with the application wizard, this is how is is configured.